# How to get scroll event of element which has mCustomScrollbar used?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I have a **div** on which i have used **mCustomScrollbar js library**, now i need to get the **scroll event** of this **div**.

Can anyone help me on this ?

here is the code i have used to set **mCustomScrollbar** on **div**.

```
<div id="content"></div>
<script>
$('#content').mCustomScrollbar();
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just use mcustomscrollebar library event of getting scroll event , you can see it on site.

Answer (score 1):

you can use `MutationObserver`

Following this code

```
var observer = new MutationObserver(function(mutations) {
  mutations.forEach(function(mutation) {
    console.log($(mutation.target).css('top'));
  });    
});

observer.observe(document.getElementById('mCSB_1_container'), { attributes : true, attributeFilter : ['style'] });
```

Here's a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/SeokjunHong/hnm30a7h/)

Comment: is there a simple method then this, as i need to use this in a very complex js already ?

Comment: I can't understand what you mean, because of my poor english. Please to explain more detail.

Comment: You mean, do you ask whether it is ok to use that code in complex js code?